# How to remove duplicate headers from a file except first occurrence in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file like below.

file1:

```
No name city country
1  xyz yyyy zzz
No name city country
2 test dddd xxxx
No name city country
3  xyz yyyy zzz
```

I want to delete the duplicate lines from this file except first occurrence and save the results in the same file.

I have tried below code, but did not help.

```
header=$(head -n 1 file1)
(printf "%s\n" "$header";
 grep -vFxe "$header" file1
) > file1
```

Comment: as a good practice, add expected output for clarity... also, what if your input file had other lines like `1  xyz yyyy zzz` duplicated? should they be removed or preserved?

Comment: @Sandeep: they should be preserved.

Comment: Thank you so much @Inian and Sandeep for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simple in `Awk`, just include all the fields in the row as unique key,

```
awk '!unique[$1$2$3$4]++' file > new-file
```

which produces an output as

```
No name city country
1  xyz yyyy zzz
2 test dddd xxxx
3  xyz yyyy zzz
```

A more readable version in `Awk` consisting of a loop upto the max fields in the row (loop upto `NF`) would be to do

```
awk '{key=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) key=key$i;}!unique[key]++' file > new-file
```

(or) a much readable version from Sundeep's comment below using `$0` meaning the whole line contents

```
awk '!unique[$0]++' file
```

---

Follow-up question from OP to save the file in-place,

Latest versions of GNU Awk (since [4.1.0 released](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.awk/browse_thread/thread/40ce7554f025c382)), have the option of ["inplace" file editing](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html):

> [...] The "inplace" extension, built using the new facility, can be used to simulate the GNU "`sed -i`" feature. [...]

Example usage:

```
gawk -i inplace '{key=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) key=key$i;}!unique[key]++' file
```

To keep the backup:

```
gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak '{key=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) key=key$i;}!unique[key]++' file
```

(or) if your `Awk` does not support that, use shell built-ins

```
tmp=$(mktemp) 
awk '{key=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) key=key$i;}!unique[key]++' file > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file
```